# Trying to scrape a dynamic javascript table with Selenium, but getting "Unable to locate element"

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

How can I scrape the information of this website (https://polkadot.subscan.io/account/12xtAYsRUrmbniiWQqJtECiBQrMn8AypQcXhnQAc6RB6XkLW?tab=transfer) using Selenium?

The main goal is to scrape the "From, To, Value and Time" information and add it to a pandas dataframe, then "play with it".

Since I can't scrape it, I can't add it to a dataframe.

I've tried, and failed using basic "inspect, and copy xpath" methods in chrome.

Here's the code:

```
link = "https://dotscan.com/account/13UVJyLnbVp9RBZYFwFGyDvVd1y27Tt8tkntv6Q7JVPhFsTB?tab=transfers"
driver.get(link)
download_btn = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[@id='rc-tabs-3-panel-1']/div/div[1]/div/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[6]/div/a")
download_btn.click()
```

This is the error message I get:

> Message: no such element: Unable to locate element

Comment: The site was built specifically with anti-scraping measures so you will be fighting with the site owner in a cat-and-mouse game to get their data. I see that they also offer an API. Why not get a trial plan and see if it works for you?

Comment: I can't find to get access to that API, It would love to use it actually!

Comment: https://support.subscan.io/#introduction

Answer (score 0):

You don't need Selenium for this, regular `requests` would be enough. If you open your browser and check the Network tab inside dev tools, you can see that it is getting data from API, in your case the endpoint is `https://polkadot.webapi.subscan.io/api/v2/scan/transfers` and parameters are `row=10`, `page=0`, and `address=12xtAYsRUrmbniiWQqJtECiBQrMn8AypQcXhnQAc6RB6XkLW`.

If you combine it all together and provide the User-Agent as it seems to be required for the API to respond, you can come up with this instead:

```
import requests

header = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0"}
params = {
    "row": 10,
    "page": 0,
    "address": "12xtAYsRUrmbniiWQqJtECiBQrMn8AypQcXhnQAc6RB6XkLW"
}

result = requests.get(
    "https://polkadot.webapi.subscan.io/api/v2/scan/transfers",
    params=params,
    headers=header
)

print(result.json())
```

Comment: AMAZING! Just a couple of things that maybe you can give a hand wo a newbie like me.

- I can't find the endpoint (and parameters) you mentioned in chrome, do you know how can I find it?

Comment: Sure @AlejandroCastillo :) In the Dev Tools, in the Network tab, select "Fetch/XHR" at the top and refresh the page, you will see bunch of requests there. Find the one you're interested in, in your case `transfers` and you can see the URL. [Here's the screenshot.](https://i.imgur.com/aqUW8le.png)